# What is the meaning of OTOH abbreviation?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, expressions, abbreviations

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600189/2989289) at StackOverflow, the OTOH expression was used, but I couldn't get this by the context. What it means?

Comment: OTOH generally refers to On The Other Hand

Comment: You're right, thanks for the clarification! Would you like to put this in a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OTOH is an abbreviation for the phrase

> On The Other Hand

It means to present factors which support opposing opinions.